# document.execCommand('bold',false,true) does not work with jquery on("click", function(){})

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do rich text editing with javascript and jquery.

I want to create a button to embolden selected text in a content editable div. When I tried with the following code, I get the expected result.

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid; " class="editor"></div>
<button class='bold' onclick="document.execCommand('bold',false,true);">B</button>
```

However, when I used jquery to do the same thing, it was not working.

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid; " class="editor"></div>
<button class='bold'>B</button>


$(function(){
    $("button.class").on("click",function(){
        document.execCommand('bold',false,true);
    })
})
```

Why isn't jquery working for my problem ?

Comment: Probably because you have no buttons with a class of....`class`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("button.class").on("click",function(){
```

Change this to

```
$("button.bold").on("click",function(){
```

Comment: Ohhh stupid me ! thank you!! will accept your answer later

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 0):

This is you can do and I hope this will definitely work.

```
 $('.bold').click(function(){});
```